# How to create new columns from Pandas datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe df with a datetime column. The total dataframe has 20 million rows, for convenience I just take 3 rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0,3), unit='h', origin='2018-08-01 00:00:00')

                 Date
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00
```

From the datetime I would like create new columns '00_hrs', '01_hrs', '02_hrs', (etc. until '23_hrs') where the values are either 0 or 1. 1 when the hour of the given datetime is applicable to the hour given in the column and 0 else.

Result should look like:

```
                 Date 00_hrs  01_hrs 02_hrs ... 23_hrs
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00    1      0     0          0
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00    0      1     0          0
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00    0      0     1          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with hours generated by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and then add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H_hrs')))
print (df)
                 Date  00_hrs  01_hrs  02_hrs
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00       1       0       0
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00       0       1       0
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00       0       0       1
```

If possible some hours missing is possible add them by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
hours = [f'{n:02}_hrs' for n in range(24)]
df = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H_hrs'))
                .reindex(hours, axis=1, fill_value=0)))
print (df)
                 Date  00_hrs  01_hrs  02_hrs  03_hrs  04_hrs  05_hrs  06_hrs  \
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00       1       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00       0       1       0       0       0       0       0   
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00       0       0       1       0       0       0       0   

   07_hrs  08_hrs  09_hrs  10_hrs  11_hrs  12_hrs  13_hrs  14_hrs  15_hrs  \
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   

   16_hrs  17_hrs  18_hrs  19_hrs  20_hrs  21_hrs  22_hrs  23_hrs  
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thanks, result looks as desired. How do I get a list of all column names with XX_hrs in it? My dataframe also has other column names in it, therefore the following doesn't work:
`col_list = [] 
    for item in df.columns:
     col_list.append(item)`

Comment: simpliest is `df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H_hrs')))` split to `df1 = pd.get_dummies(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H_hrs'))` and `df = df.join(df1)` and then `print (df1.column)`